# ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 5055 to array axis with dimension 17

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I was trying to plot a bar chart for low vs high vote average sum of revenues and I ran into this error. I am still a beginner and have no idea how to solve it, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
%matplotlib inline

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
df_count_0value_revenue= df.groupby('revenue').count()['id']
df_count_0value_revenue.head()  
df['revenue']=df['revenue'].replace(0, np.NaN)

high_vote_average= df.query('vote_average > 6.000000')
Low_vote_average= df.query('vote_average  < 6.000000')
sum_low_average= Low_vote_average['revenue'].sum()
sum_high_average=high_vote_average['revenue'].sum()

Locations=['Low','High']
Heights=[sum_low_average,sum_high_average]
labels=[Low_vote_average,high_vote_average]
*plt.bar(Locations,Heights,tick_label=labels)<--
plt.title('Sum of Total revenue per Vote average level')
plt.xlabel('Vote Average level')
plt.ylabel('Sum of Total revenue')
```

The dataset is TMDB 5000 movies on Kaggle
I expect a bar graph with two bars one for low average and one for high, but I keep receiving the following error:

> cannot copy sequence with size 5055 to array axis with dimension 17

Comment: Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, you should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Sheldore just did! appreciate the help